# Trigger AppCache Download

Tags: updatesourcetrigger, html5-appcache

Is there a way to trigger an application cache download? I've seen several webapps which provide a download for offline storage button, but it seems there's no event for this.

Dynamically changing the manifest file in the  tag doesn't work too.

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there it is: `window.applicationCache.update()`